# Error: 403 Forbidden: Call type exceeds Solana 1.9.13 version limit for max account size

Tags: solana, solana-web3js

I am trying to get minted editions of a collection, by using the accepted answer of this post below:

[How to find all NFTs minted from a v2 candy machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70597753/how-to-find-all-nfts-minted-from-a-v2-candy-machine)

However when I try to query, I am getting the error as per the title:

`Error: 403 Forbidden: Call type exceeds Solana 1.9.13 version limit for max account size.`

Comment: can you share, your implementation. The only part of invocation of `connection.getProgramAccounts(` would suffice to understand what are you doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at https://www.theindex.io/.  Their rpc (https://rpc.theindex.io) works for a limited set of rpc calls getProgramAccounts being one of them.

from the code at the link posted in the original question replace

```
const connection = new Connection('mainnet-beta');
```

with

```
const connection = new Connection('https://rpc.theindex.io', 'finalized');
```

This worked for me when I got the same error.

For some background on the issue:

The linked code uses getProgramAccounts which apparently creates issues for validators. (see the overview from the solana docs here https://docs.solana.com/developing/plugins/geyser-plugins, "Validators under heavy RPC loads, such as when serving getProgramAccounts calls, can fall behind the network.")