# How to get all the NFTs for Metaplex Candy Machine without using the Metaplex JS SDK?

Tags: solana, nft, metaplex

I want to fetch all the NFT lists for the candy machine.
Of course, if we use the [Metaplex JS SDK](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js) it will be easy.

But I'd love to fetch NFTs by using Solana Web3 APIs.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great answer here already: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70601874/18965981

What you have to do is run a GPA against the candy machine v2 program to find all the mint addresses.

```js
import { Connection, clusterApiUrl, PublicKey } from '@solana/web3.js';
import bs58 from 'bs58';

const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl('mainnet-beta'));
const MAX_NAME_LENGTH = 32;
const MAX_URI_LENGTH = 200;
const MAX_SYMBOL_LENGTH = 10;
const MAX_CREATOR_LEN = 32 + 1 + 1;
const MAX_CREATOR_LIMIT = 5;
const MAX_DATA_SIZE = 4 + MAX_NAME_LENGTH + 4 + MAX_SYMBOL_LENGTH + 4 + MAX_URI_LENGTH + 2 + 1 + 4 + MAX_CREATOR_LIMIT * MAX_CREATOR_LEN;
const MAX_METADATA_LEN = 1 + 32 + 32 + MAX_DATA_SIZE + 1 + 1 + 9 + 172;
const CREATOR_ARRAY_START = 1 + 32 + 32 + 4 + MAX_NAME_LENGTH + 4 + MAX_URI_LENGTH + 4 + MAX_SYMBOL_LENGTH + 2 + 1 + 4;

const TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM = new PublicKey('metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s');
const CANDY_MACHINE_V2_PROGRAM = new PublicKey('cndy3Z4yapfJBmL3ShUp5exZKqR3z33thTzeNMm2gRZ');
const candyMachineId = new PublicKey('ENTER_YOUR_CANDY_MACHINE_ID_HERE');

const getMintAddresses = async (firstCreatorAddress: PublicKey) => {
  const metadataAccounts = await connection.getProgramAccounts(
      TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM,
      {
        // The mint address is located at byte 33 and lasts for 32 bytes.
        dataSlice: { offset: 33, length: 32 },

        filters: [
          // Only get Metadata accounts.
          { dataSize: MAX_METADATA_LEN },

          // Filter using the first creator.
          {
            memcmp: {
              offset: CREATOR_ARRAY_START,
              bytes: firstCreatorAddress.toBase58(),
            },
          },
        ],
      },
  );

  return metadataAccounts.map((metadataAccountInfo) => (
      bs58.encode(metadataAccountInfo.account.data)
  ));
};

const getCandyMachineCreator = async (candyMachine: PublicKey): Promise<[PublicKey, number]> => (
    PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
        [Buffer.from('candy_machine'), candyMachine.toBuffer()],
        CANDY_MACHINE_V2_PROGRAM,
    )
);

(async () => {

  const candyMachineCreator = await getCandyMachineCreator(candyMachineId);
  getMintAddresses(candyMachineCreator[0]);

})();
```